# CVS vs SVN vs GIT vs anyother

Tags: repository, git, svn

CVS is being used in my workplace and I've no much knowledge of cvs other than installing and creating cvs users and I heard developers share their project with eclipse or something like that. I'm asked to check for best repositories which offers advanced features giving the hints SVN and GIT. If any one using these repositories please short list their features and if possible with links of good installation guides and a bit information of what the eclipse to do with these repositories.

Thank you!

Comment: this should be on super user or another stack exchange site since it's not related to ubuntu.

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control?sort=votes&pagesize=30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider what kind of repository system your team needs to function effectivly. The main difference is between:

- **Centralised Repositories** - CVS, SVN, Simple File Server, etc
- **Decentralised Repositories** - Git, Mercurial, Bzr

I make this distinction now, because if you move from cvs to git, you will need to read up on what it means to have decentralised repositories. The new kinds of work-flows you need to develop will make development easier and more efficient for bigger teams, but the change in workflows will make your first attempts fail as you make assumptions about how it's supposed to work.

Here in the Ubuntu world we use [Bazaar (bzr)](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) which is a very good decentralised system written in python and based on mercurial. It's fairly easy to set up a server and the commands and extensions available are well developed. Eclipse has a very good bzr plugin. Launchpad and GNU's Savana use bzr by default and it's my personal first choice.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) is also another fantastic repository system. Developed by Torvalds himself after his disastrous time with a proprietary system, GIT is lightning fast and only slightly harder to use than bzr. It's used by github, gnome and several other projects as their main repository system after using svn.

Both are available in the Ubuntu repositories, as well as a ton of extensions.

I wouldn't use svn or any other centralised repository unless you have a very small team and know what you're doing.

Comment: Good information!. I've to read about what Centralised & Decentralised reposotories.